# CDI Inject dependencies from Injection Point owner

Tags: java, cdi

I have a class called Container:

```
public class Container {

    @Inject
    ServiceA serviceA;

    @Inject
    ServiceB serviceB;

}
```

ServiceB depends on serviceA:

```
public class ServiceB {

    @Inject 
    ServiceA serviceA;
}
```

Inside my app there can be several containers. Now, is there any trick to inject into ServiceB this instance of ServiceA which has been injected into the same Container instance as ServiceB?

Comment: Did it not work that way?  What did you try?

Comment: @IanMcLaird: By default, the injection will be in dependent scope, and every injectable object has its own instance of dependent scope. At least, that's my understanding, which could be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

you should define a @Singleton scope for your object. put @Singleton annotation to ServiceA class

For example

```
@Singleton
public class ServiceA  { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class as either `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Singleton`, this will ensure that there will be only one instance of the `ServiceA` in your application. This instance will be created during first injection of this bean.

P.S. I would prefer `@ApplicationScoped` as suggested in the Weld [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1964) because `@Singleton` doesn't have a proxy object which can use problems during serialization.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to inject different instances of `ServiceA` into different `Container` instances, so singleton pattern is not an option for me. What i need is sort of singleton-per-container pattern here

Comment: You can use EJBs Singletons which are unique per JVM (I don't know if the same thing applies for CDI ones) but I am afraid there is no other way how to achieve what you want...

Answer (score 0):

you could create a CDI Extension with a custom scope @ContainerScope  "ContainerScopeExtension"...

how to make a custom scope can be read here:
https://rpestano.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/cdi-custom-scope/

The implementation of such a ContainerScopeExtension could be as following:

1. every container instance for the same request is remembered in a "container cache"
2. while creating a service instance. get the injection point of the current "producer" request. if the injection point is a controller, check if there is already a service produces for this container. (for example inside a "service per container cache"). otherwise create a new service instance and put it inside the "service cache" and remember the container of this service instance.
3. if the injection point is a service.. then get the "parent" service instance of the cache, to find the container instance of the "parent" service. and then you can check if there is already a instance of the service to be produced for found container...
4. etc...

Comment: but i think there could also be a designing problem from the whole application...